# Apple rejected - can not reproduce crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data, crash

Apple rejected my app with a crash log indicating that they have tested it on an iPhone 6 with iOS 8.0.2. I tested my app with the same iPhone 6 and also on 8.0.2, it works perfect. I tried it with testflight via iTunesConnect, assuming, that this is exactly the same away as Apple does their testing - obviously not!

Does anyone have an idea, how I can solve that issue (already got in contact with the review team, but they couldn't help, as they say they are not technical support and just test the apps.

The problem I have is (from my point of view anyway strange): It crashes when it add the persistent store:

```
       NSError *error = nil;
_persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {
    /*
     Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately. abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

     Typical reasons for an error here include:
     * The persistent store is not accessible;
     * The schema for the persistent store is incompatible with current managed object model.
     Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.


     If the persistent store is not accessible, there is typically something wrong with the file path. Often, a file URL is pointing into the application's resources directory instead of a writeable directory.

     If you encounter schema incompatibility errors during development, you can reduce their frequency by:
     * Simply deleting the existing store:
     [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:storeURL error:nil]

     * Performing automatic lightweight migration by passing the following dictionary as the options parameter:
     @{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:@YES, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption:@YES}

     Lightweight migration will only work for a limited set of schema changes; consult "Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration Programming Guide" for details.

     */
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}
```

It obviously crashes because I have the `abort()`statement still in there, but I'm not sure what to do instead (i.e to handle the problem - just delete and try to add the store again?)

As it works perfect on my iPhone, I assume, that it is not one of the problems listed in the source code (like directory, model etc. am I right?
I'm struggling with that now for several days, any help or idea is more than appreciated!!

Comment: Did you change the model? try installing the old version, add some data and then update the app, maybe you have some problem with data migration.

Comment: check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13806849/handling-errors-in-addpersistentstorewithtype

Comment: thanks for your comments. i did not change the model, and it works fine when I test it-  so I assume this can not be the reason.

Comment: @kabarga, thanks for the link, sounds like a good idea, but as I can not recreate I would need to submit it again to Apple and hope it will work - or do you have another idea in mind?

Comment: you can fix it based on the link above, check it many times and remove abort() line. in our app we are using abort in some places only in DEBUG mode. Set also options NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption to YES

Comment: also check if you call this method once. you call it when you create managedObjectContext. So, check if you, for some reason, could create it in parallel from 2 threads.

Comment: did that, i.e. I call it only once. Will give it a try. Do you have any idea, why I can not reproduce the crash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Common reason for this to happen is when there is already a file at storeURL and it does not conform to model that you specify.

As a fix for that here is what you can do
1) Enable lightweight migration
2) Delete existing file and try again

```
NSDictionary *options = @{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: @YES,
                          NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: @YES
                          };
BOOL successOfAdding = [_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                                                    configuration:nil
                                                                              URL:storeURL
                                                                          options:options
                                                                            error:&error] != nil;
if (successOfAdding == NO)
{
    // Check if the database is there.
    // If it is there, it most likely means that model has changed significantly.
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:storeURL.path])
    { 
        // Delete the database
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:storeURL error:nil];
        // Trying to add a database to the coordinator again
        successOfAdding = [_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType: NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error] != nil;
        if (successOfAdding == NO)
        {
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }
```

And about rejection - do you have previous versions of your app? 
Also, where are you attempting to store your database? May be there is no access to that path?

Comment: thanks for your comment. Its the first release of the app, so there is no former version  of the database. I store the  database in `[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];` The problem is, it works for me, but somehow not for apple review team

Comment: the other problem is, if - for whatever reason - the user has updated the database and I get then a problem with the persistent store, I would delete all his data.

Comment: Reason could be: it is forbidden to store databases in Documents directory unless you have some user-generated data because contents of Documents directory can be synchronised between devices. It is unlikely but in review access to Documents may be blocked

Comment: In case of storing user data you should use lightweight or custom migration. User cannot update the database himself, it is updated only if you change the model

Comment: sorry, when I said update the database, I meant the content, not the structure (the user can/should enter data - thats the purpose of the database in that app). Good idea with the doc directory, but I just checked, it is the right place (also in iOS 8). I guess I try the thing with the migration parameters and see what the review team figures out. If it does not help I guess I will ask the technical support, as I'm simply lost if it still not work and can not be recreated.

Comment: @Red also check this out https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2406/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40014932-CH1-FURTHER_READING and mentioned articles. May be you should use application support directory instead

Comment: Im having the same issue with addPersistentStoreWithType failing during the App Store review process. Looking at your SO questions since this one it looks like you have the issue sorted out - was it purely using this answer or did you have to take any further steps? Thanks